# Number of permutations with conditions on sum of elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to model game with dice. I am throwing three dice, sum up results on them. If result is equal or less than given number, that's a success, if not - failure.
Probability function $p(n)$ is defined on $n$ from 3 to 18. I suspect it's recursive: $p(n) = p(n-1)$ + number of combinations (permutations?), elements of which sum to n. As I have a probability table, I can guess $p(3)=1/216;$ $ p(4) = p(3) + 3/216;$ $ p(5) = p(4) + 6/216$. My problem is that I can't understand, how to calculate for given n number of combinations (permutations?) which sum to given n. Anyone can give any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions[assuming distinct die, I have a method for identical die too!]:
$$\text{Coefficient of }x^n\text{ in }\left(\sum_{k=1}^6x^k\right)^3$$
That would be in:
$$\left(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\right)^3=(1-x^7)^3(1-x)^{-3}$$
I hope you can use the binomial theorem now?
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk a^kb^{n-k}\\\binom nr=\binom{n+r-1}r\qquad(n<0)$$

Comment: Nope, it's really not.

Comment: @DarkArchon see edit.

Comment: I am sorry, but it isn't any clearer to me. Still don't understand that is this thing and how it works.

Comment: @DarkArchon I wish to create an explanatory question on this topic, w8.

Comment: @Elaqqad that comment is uninformative, please explain what's wrong and i will gladly accept my mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry for the comment, when you develop the product you will have a coefficient $1$ of $x^{63}$ which means that there is some $3$ elements which sum to $63$ but the maximal degrre of your polynomial would be $18$, now it's correct!

Comment: @Elaqqad found and corrected.edited.

Comment: In my mind, I would look at $(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$.  (Ah, it seems you just edited to that).  I will mention for the OP's benefit, that the coefficient of the $x^n$ term here is the number of ways to add to exactly $n$ with three dice.  To find the probability of winning, add together the coefficients of terms with degree less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, further edited.